# Frequency count from ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to access Document Frequency for each word in query and response. By setting the explain = true parameter in query. Any proper explanation of explain = true response apart from documentation might be helpful. It does not clearly explains the response.

```
GET  /_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match":{
               "title":"lalala Black Goober Tshirt"
            }
        }


    }
},
"size":1,
"explain": true, 
"fields": ["title" , "price"]
}
```

But the results are not consistent depending on whether some of the words are missing or not. I need to find the frequency of each word  in the response if present in my elasticsearch.